# Options for repeated distributed task

Tags: distributed-computing, message-queue

## Scenario

My project has a need to periodically scan the database and notify administrators for particular issues. For example:

- Any errors in the logs since last update?
- Do values match expected value from external source?
- New clients?

My nodes (plain old windows services) are currently using Azure Service Bus [QueueClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.aspx) for other distributed tasks, so my original thought was to [do something with this same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509893/recurring-azure-service-bus-queue-messages). However, this proved pretty challenging (see below).

From brainstorming I've come up with the following possible options:

### Azure ServiceBus QueueClient

**Description:** Upon receiving a task, the message handler will enqueue a new message set for X in the future.

*For example:*

```
var client = QueueClient.Create("DetectErrors");
var options = /* ... */

client.OnMessage((message) => {
    client.Send(new BrokeredMessage() {
        ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
    });

    if (DetectStuffInDb())
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
}, options)
```

**Issue:** *How to fire that 1st message?* This needs to fire when there is no pending message and only fire a single message (not one per node as might be the case if all nodes start the same time).

### Azure QueueClient + WebJob

**Description:** Use an Azure Webjob to hit an endpoint on my WebApi, which will enqueue a new message. (a slight derivation of this would be to use Azure Automation + Runbook to enqueue a message)

**Issue:** Seems odd to make so many 'hops' to handle each task. `[WebJob] -> [WebApi] -> [Queue] -> [Node]`. Additionally, this would make development\testing a little difficult since the WebJob may not have access to a localhost WebApi.

### Task.Delay + DB

**Description:** Use Task.Delay to space out recurring tasks on each distributed node & verify with the DB if another node is currently handling the task. Something like

```
var id = Cmd("SELECT [Id] FROM [T]");
while (true)
{
    var newId = Guid.NewGuid();
    Cmd("UPDATE [T] SET [Id] = '<newId>' WHERE [Id] = '<id>'");
    id = Cmd("SELECT [Id] FROM [T]");

    if (newId == id)
    {
        if (DetectStuffInDb())
        {
            SendEmail();
        }
    }

    await Task.Delay(x);
}
```

**Issues:** Requires a lot of querying of the database by all the nodes.

## Question

- Any suggestions to how to best handle this scenario?
- Is there a better way to handle this scenario that doesn't require timed\recurring tasks?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the necessity to use timed tasks.  If you want a message to be present once a new client is created, why wait?

Comment: I actually don't want the message to be made immediately. The use case for the new client is to inform the admin that X clients have been added since the last check.

Comment: That makes things unnecessarily complicated.  Have you considered writing a line in a messages table indicating the creation of a new client, and inside the program, once a day it searches for new messages and groups those that share the same message type?

Comment: I think that's basically what I'm attempting (unless I'm misunderstanding you). Specifically the "once a day it searches..." is what I'm having an issue with. The "line in a messages table" could be assumed to be in my "DetectStuffInDb()" method, I think. How would you implement this so that it can be executed at a particular time (either daily or hourly or whatever) on one of multiple possible machines?

Comment: ...or are you suggesting that it doesn't need to be distributed & instead just have a single process that sits idle until a certain time.

Comment: I would try to eliminate the necessity for you to consider *when* the task occurs and just focus on the how.  You could easily schedule a task to trigger once a day that simply tells the server to perform this check.  If you have multiple servers, just make sure you only have one task per database.  Did that answer your question?  I'm still not convinced that I've understood your dilemma.

Comment: I think I'm missing the obvious regarding "You could easily schedule a task..." :) Maybe I'm looking for a programming way to handle this when there's a more obvious execution way (i.e. task scheduler)

Comment: These types of things get complicated in a hurry.  My advice is to depend on cron or windows task scheduler to perform routine operations.  Alternatively, you could try to find a library that specializes in this.  I wouldn't attempt to implement a scheduler.  It has been done enough times that it doesn't merit the risk you'd take to try it yourself.

Comment: @Neil My application is currently hosted in a Azure VM, so Task Scheduler is certainly an option. Last night I even got a dummy command-line program running hourly on one of my servers (though a small pain to get setup in Octopus). Throw something in an answer & I'll give you some fake internet points. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, added my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to not overcomplicate your program attempting to accomodate task scheduling.  When it comes to these things, I generally prefer to hinge on cron or windows task scheduler to deal with the specifics of *when*.  This leaves you the possibility to focus only on the how, and you can disregard having to worry about an interface and all that entails in order to set up a scheduled task.

Just create a simple batch file that performs the request to your server and schedule it to run once a day.  I imagine this is the sort of thing that a systems administrator would have to deal with and certainly not your typical user, so you can make your boss happy by getting it up and working in less time and still having all the functionality you potentially require.  While it is true that this makes your program operating system dependent, it would take little work to get the same thing to work using cron, and it would seem in your case, this discussion is not even relevant.

Alternatively, you could search for a library that provides this support.  In any case, I would strongly encourage you to resist the temptation to code this yourself.  This is the type of thing that has been done many times over, and if you attempted to do it yourself, aside from lose time, you might discover some serious issues down the road that, if you're lucky, won't get you fired.  Don't take the risk and don't reinvent the wheel.  It is my personal idea that the best of us programmers aren't those who can write a better version of an algorithm than you, but rather those who gracefully admit that such things have already been written and must only be pieced together with care.

Please let me know how it turns out.  :)